# How to compute a special double integral

Tags: calculus

Let $0<\alpha<2.$ How to compute the following double integral?
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dxdy}{|x-y|^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}
$$

Comment: $u=x$ and $v=x-y$ might be a substitution...

Answer (score 3):

If you make the suggested substitution (with $u=x , v = x-y$), you have the integral
$$
\iint_{[0,1] \times [0,1]} \frac{dx \, dy}{ | x-y |^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} }
=
\iint_{\left\{ (u,v) \in [0,1] \times [u, u-1] \right\} } | v |^{- \frac{\alpha}{2}} \left| \frac{\partial (u,v)}{ \partial (x,y)} \right| du \, dv .
$$
Now, the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation given by 
$$
\left| \frac{\partial (u,v)}{ \partial (x,y)} \right|
=
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 \\
\end{vmatrix}
= -1 ,
$$
so that the integral is 
$$
\iint_{\left\{ (u,v) \in [0,1] \times [u, u-1] \right\} } | v |^{- \frac{\alpha}{2}} \left| \frac{\partial (u,v)}{ \partial (x,y)} \right| du \, dv 
=
\int_{0} ^1 
\left(
-1 \cdot \int_{u} ^{u-1} 
| v |^{- \frac{\alpha}{2}} dv 
\right) 
du
=
\int_{0} ^1 
\left(
\int_{u-1} ^{u} 
| v |^{- \frac{\alpha}{2}} dv 
\right) 
du .
$$
Now, this can be simplified as 
$$
\int_{0} ^1 
\left(
\int_{u-1} ^{u} 
| v |^{- \frac{\alpha}{2}} dv 
\right) 
du 
=
\int_{0} ^1 
\left(
\int_{u-1} ^{\lceil u - 1 \rceil} 
(-v)^{- \frac{\alpha}{2}} dv 
+
\int_{\lceil u - 1 \rceil}  ^u
v^{- \frac{\alpha}{2}} dv 
\right) 
du 
$$ 
which is 
$$
\int_{0} ^1 
\left(
\int_{\lceil u - 1 \rceil}  ^u
v^{- \frac{\alpha}{2}} dv 
-
\int_{u-1} ^{\lceil u - 1 \rceil} 
(-v)^{- \frac{\alpha}{2}} d(-v) 
\right) 
du 
=
\int_{0} ^1 
\left(
\frac{1}{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} \cdot
v^{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} 
\Big|_{\lceil u - 1 \rceil} ^u
-
\frac{1}{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} \cdot
(-v)^{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} 
\Big|_{u-1} ^{\lceil u - 1 \rceil}
\right) 
du 
.
$$
After some simplification, this integral becomes 
$$
\frac{1}{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} \cdot
\int_{0} ^1 
\left(
u^{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} - {\lceil u - 1 \rceil}^{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} - {\lfloor 1 - u \rfloor}^{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} + (1-u)^{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}}
\right) 
du \\
=
\frac{1}{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} \cdot
\left(
\int_{0} ^1 
u^{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} + (1-u)^{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}}
du 
-
\int_{0} ^1 
{\lceil u - 1 \rceil}^{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} + {\lfloor 1 - u \rfloor}^{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}}du 
\right)
$$
to which the second integral doesn't contribute (which can be seen as the functions in question vanish except on a set of measure 0 - a point set). Hence this becomes
$$ 
=
\frac{1}{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{{2 - \frac{\alpha}{2}}}
\left(
u^{2 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} - (1-u)^{2 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} \right) \Big|_0 ^1 .
$$
Finally, we arrive at the answer
$$
\frac{1}{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}} 
\cdot \frac{1}{{2 - \frac{\alpha}{2}}}
\cdot 2
=
\frac{8}{(2-a)(4-a)} .
$$

Comment: Ahh, I was wondering where an error had crept in - it certainly made no sense to integrate $|\cdot|$ and get a negative value! Thanks, for that - it'll teach me to do math when I'm tired!

Comment: @Florian already noted - thanks for the heads up, I am editing the answer now.

Comment: @FrancescoAlem. Well, I guess I better make that edit then!

Answer (score 1):

We substitute $x' = \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y' = \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}$. The Jacobian of the transformation is $1$. This parameter change rotates the plane by $45°$ and we derive
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{dx\, dy}{|x-y|^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}} &= \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \int_{-y'}^{y'} \frac{1}{|\sqrt{2}x'|^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}} dx'\, dy'+\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\sqrt{2}+y'}^{\sqrt{2}-y'}\frac{1}{|\sqrt{2}x'|^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}} dx'\, dy'\\
&=4\cdot 2^{-\frac{\alpha}{4}}\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \int_{0}^{y'} \frac{1}{(x')^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}} dx'\, dy'\\
&= 4\cdot 2^{-\frac{\alpha}{4}}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{(y')^{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}} dy'\\
&=\frac{8}{(2-\alpha)(4-\alpha)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: an easier transformation is: 
$\begin{cases}
x=v+u\\
y=v-u\\
\mbox{dx}\wedge\mbox{dy}=2\mbox{du}\wedge\mbox{dv}
\end{cases}$

Comment: Hey Florian - do you mind taking a look at my edited work? I decided to try and stick with it using the same change of variables, and it worked out alright except apparently I seem to have dropped a factor of $2^{\frac{\alpha}{4}}$ and I am having difficulty seeing where...

Comment: @izœc: You made me realize an error in my solution. Thanks! Yours seems fine now.

Comment: Oh, excellent, glad that worked out! Thanks.